# extract or grep value from xml file

Tags: xml, grep, redhat, xmlstarlet

I am working with xgrep and xmlgrep to find certain information from an XML file (http://pastebin.com/1BJEWVJJ)

Sample snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cXML.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.014/cXML.dtd">
<cXML xml:lang="en" payloadID="2015-02-24T14:17:26_3764135.ConfirmationRequest@axis.mincom.com" timestamp="2015-02-24T14:17:26+10:00">
<Header>
<From>
<Credential domain="SpotlessBranchID">
<Identity>
L678</Identity>
</Credential>
<Credential domain="SupplierCustno">
<Identity>
SPOWOC</Identity>
</Credential>
<Credential domain="MincomAxis">
<Identity>
101000026139003</Identity>
</Credential>
</From>
<To>
<Credential domain="SpotlessSAPSupplierID">
<Identity>
0002010354</Identity>
</Credential>
<Credential domain="SpotlessSupplierID">
<Identity>
0002010354</Identity>
</Credential>
```

I want to extract the SpotLessSupplierID Identity value (e.g. 0002010354)

I tried `xgrep -s 'Credential:Identity/.*/' PO_3764135.xml` but I get too much output (too many "Credential"s)

```
<!--         Start of node set (Search: Credential:Identity/.*/)                 -->
<!--         Node   0 in node set               -->
<Credential domain="SpotlessBranchID">
  <Identity>L678</Identity>
</Credential>

<!--         Node   1 in node set               -->
<Credential domain="SupplierCustno">
  <Identity>SPOWOC</Identity>
</Credential>

<!--         Node   2 in node set               -->
<Credential domain="MincomAxis">
  <Identity>101000026139003</Identity>
</Credential>

<!--         Node   3 in node set               -->
<Credential domain="SpotlessSAPSupplierID">
  <Identity>0002010354</Identity>
</Credential>

<!--         Node   4 in node set               -->
<Credential domain="SpotlessSupplierID">
  <Identity>0002010354</Identity>
</Credential>

<!--         Node   5 in node set               -->
<Credential domain="MincomAxis">
  <Identity>101000321896001</Identity>
</Credential>

<!--         Node   6 in node set               -->
<Credential domain="SpotlessBranchID">
  <Identity>L678</Identity>
</Credential>

<!--         Node   7 in node set               -->
<Credential domain="MincomAxisTPID">
  <Identity>101000026139</Identity>
</Credential>

<!--         End of node set                    -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XmlStarlet** is a very useful tool in theses cases, you can download it and try this :

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//header/To/Credential[@domain = 'SpotlessSAPSupplierID']" -v Identity -n /path_to_your_xml_file
```

for documentation : this is a best link :
[XmlStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html)

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Could you explain the command a little?

Comment: well , "sel" means that this is a select query , we use -t option to mention that we are using a template for querying the XML document , -m option to match a specific path between markups in the xml doc , -v indicates the value of the markup that we are looking for. -n is just useful to print a new line , if you are executing your script in a terminal , it's useful sometimes. i edited my response , check the link below for documentation. there is everything.